# When is a typemap necessary for swig?

Tags: perl, swig

I have such a function in `.i` file:

```
t_demo * t struct_new();
```

It seems I don't need any typemaps,it just works.
After converting I can use it directly:

```
use test;

$a = test::struct_new;
```

When is a typemap necessary for swig?

Answer (score 0):

For example, we can create "out" typemap for t_demo and return hash populated with selected members of this struct:

```
%typemap(out) t_demo {
  HV* tmp = newHV();

  SV* t_data = newSViv($1.int_field1);
  hv_store(tmp, "int_field1", 4, t_data, 0);

  $result = sv_2mortal(newRV_noinc((SV*) tmp));
  argvi++;
}
```

Many more uses are documented in swig manual.

Comment: But I can get the fields with accessor functions,right?So this is not necessary...

Comment: "Typemaps are generally not a required part of using SWIG", but this may be needed for some edge cases - e.g. no accessors and they can't be added.

Comment: That make sense.BTW,does swig's `-shadow` option only work with c++? I tried to get it work with c structures but not working...